# How to count cart using session user

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, shopping-cart

I am currently working on a project on a shopping cart. I already done the cart but somehow I cannot count the cart and **it keep shows 0.** **I already check that the session for the user is grabbed.**

This is the method I used:

```
    //check cart count
    public int getCartCount(string Username)
    {

        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection msqlConnection = null;
        msqlConnection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=localhost;User Id=root;password=rootPassw0rd;Persist Security Info=False;database=infosec;Integrated Security=False");
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand msqlCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        //define the connection used by the command object
        msqlCommand.Connection = msqlConnection;

        msqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shoppingcart WHERE Item_Id = @Username ";
        msqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", _Username);

        msqlConnection.Open();

        string nofRow = "";

        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader msqlReader = msqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (msqlReader.Read())
        {
            nofRow = msqlReader["COUNT(*)"].ToString();
        }

        msqlConnection.Close();
        msqlConnection.Close();
        msqlReader.Dispose();

        int cart = Convert.ToInt32(nofRow);


        return cart;
```

This is the code behind for the .axps page:

```
 //cart increase if there items added.
        if (Session["customer_Username"] == null)
        {
            cartCount.InnerText = "Cart (0)";
        }
        else
        {
            cartBLL cBLL = new cartBLL();
            string a = Session["customer_Username"].ToString();
            int count = cBLL.getCartCount(a);
            cartCount.InnerText = "Cart (" + count + ")";
        }
```

Hope you all can help me find the problems.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line :

```
nofRow = msqlReader["COUNT(*)"].ToString();
```

To

```
nofRow = msqlReader[0].ToString();
```

Perhaps, it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

*Well*, maybe `MySqlDataReader` can have a problem with reading of `"COUNT(*)"` column (*I have not tried yet*).

Another point, when you read `"COUNT(*)"` column with `msqlReader["COUNT(*)"]`, your result can be `null` and `Convert.ToInt32(null)` generates `0`. (*But this is very unlikely*)

But more important, using `MySqlDataReader` is not a good choice in your case. Since you using `COUNT(*)` to get row counts, [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) is a better choice which returns first column of first row in your query.

```
msqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shoppingcart WHERE Item_Id = @Username ";
msqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", _Username);
int cart = (int)msqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` like;

```
using(MySqlConnection msqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(conString))
using(MySqlCommand msqlCommand = myCon.CreateCommand())
{
     //
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner in c#, can give me the example for my case.

Comment: @Samuel What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

- Verify that `string a = Session["customer_Username"].ToString();` does return the username.
- Change `nofRow = msqlReader["COUNT(*)"].ToString();` to `nofRow = msqlReader[0].ToString();`. Your query has the count aggregate function in it.
- Verify that `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shoppingcart WHERE Item_Id = @Username` does pull in value. @Username needs to be replaced by the value that you have from the session.
- Looks like you have a typo in this line `msqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", _Username);`. `_Username` should be `Username`.